# Git sublime package does not work

Tags: sublimetext2, git-push, git-diff

Git diff in my sublime text throws following error

```
error: Malformed value for push.default: simple
error: Must be one of nothing, matching, tracking or current.
fatal: bad config file line 7 in /Users/fizer/.gitconfig
```

If i remove **push.default: simple** from .gitconfig. Then it works. But when i do **git push**, it complains that it needs **push.default: simple**.

How to fix it?

Comment: Try [push]
default = current?

Comment: Now it works with  push.default: matching, but latest git suggests that it needs to **simple**.

Answer (score 2):

Sublime is using an older version of git. If you are on linux get the output of `which git` in your terminal and change your git package settings as below:

```
{
  "git_command": "/new/path/to/git"
}
```